# How to extract a href from an a class in beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract  href= in an  class but am unable to extract it.
I've tried `url = tag_variable.find("href")`, but am getting `None`.

```
<a class="product-card__name" href="/store/groceryGateway/en/Herbs/Fresh/Longo%27s-Fresh-Herbs-Basil/p/00772468010517">
<strong>
                                                                Longo's Fresh Herbs Basil</strong>
</a>
```

Comment: There are so many answers to this on Stackoverflow. It is always worth searching on SO first. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element) will help with reading HTML and [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) from the documentation will help with bs4

Answer (score 0):

`href` is an attribute or property of the `a` tag, not a tag object itself which `find` wants.

Assuming you have the desired `a` tag as `tag_variable`, you can use subscription like `dict`:

```
url = tag_variable["href"]
```

Comment: @KevinLiu Great. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @KevinLiu it is dict so you can also use `tag_variable.get("href")` to get `None` instead  of rasing exception if there is no `"href"`. OR `tag_variable.get("href", "default value")`